# Exclude nuget packages from source control

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

I want to exclude nuget packages from the source control, because we use our own custom packages and they change often so it generates too many unnecessary changes in the source control. Also because it seems to be the recommended way to work with packages and source control.

I followed the steps given at the link below, using the instructions with TFS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control

Automatic package restoration is enabled, but when I generate the solution, restoration fail because it try to restore Microsoft packages from our custom source instead of the nuget.org source, I don't understand why. 
For example (sorry its in french):

```
La restauration des packages NuGet a échoué pour le projet PointOfSaleWebsite : 
La version '3.2.3' du package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.fr' est introuvable.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Le package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.fr.3.2.3' est introuvable dans la source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
http://srv-tfs:8080/tfs/.../_packaging/.../nuget/v3/index.json: Le package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.fr.3.2.3' est introuvable dans la source 'http://srv-tfs:8080/tfs/.../_packaging/.../nuget/v3/index.json'.
```

I tried to add this to the NuGet.Config, but still have the same errors:

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="OurCustomSource" value="http://srv-tfs:8080/tfs/.../_packaging/.../nuget/v3/index.json" />
</packageSources>
```

I also tried to run this command in the package manager console:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

It fails with this error:

```
Update-Package : Certains packages NuGet sont manquants dans la solution. Les packages doivent être restaurés pour générer le graphique de dépendance. Restaurez les packages avant d'effectuer des opé
rations.
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 15
+ Update-Package <<<<  -Reinstall
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

Any idea why it try to restore from the wrong source ? or is it something wrong i'm doing to exclude packages from the source control ?

Comment: Are you using git or TFS-VC? In the former case what is in your `.gitignore`, in the latter your `.tfignore` file?

Comment: TFS, but correct me if i'm wrong, .tfignore has nothing to do with package restoration failing ? it only has to do with excluding packages from the source-control. The content of the .tfignore is exactly the same as the one shown at step 5 in the link included in my post.

Comment: Possibly, but how the exclusion is set up is the first thing to check. Second question: Are the missing packages ones you would expect to get from nuget or from your TFS source? (And it would help to switch to English to get translations of the error messages.)

Comment: The packages that can't be restored are from nuget, the packages from our source are restored succesfully since it only restore from that source and doesn't not try to check on nuget.org source for the other packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#build-time-restore-in-visual-studio

Step 4 especially pointed me in the right direction, it turned out that I only had by mistake uncheked the nuget.org source from the visual studio options !!

I apologize for not having seen it earlier ! I'm ashamed, such a waste of time :(

Comment: We all – from time to time – fail to see something that is subsequently "obvious". Hence the effectiveness of [rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).